# About modifying contents of NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray`, called `buttonContainer` that contains `UIButton`s. The thing is I want to change the `CGRectmake()` of every button with a new value, is there an easy way to do this?

I'm trying this but get errors:

```
[buttonContainer objectAtIndex: i].frame = CGRectmake(x,y,w,h);
```

The error I get is: property 'frame' not found on object of type 'id'.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please edit with more code so we can help you.

Comment: yep, but the problem is i think it can't be accessed and modified that way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NSMutableArray` can contain any `id` type, and the return type of `objectAtIndex` is `id` which does not has a `frame` property. If your array contains only `UIButton` then you can do this inside loop:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *) [buttonContainer objectAtIndex:i];
button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
```

Comment: great it worked, the loop i used was
for(uibutton* button in buttonContainer){


}

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is use `IBOutletCollection`.

You declare them in your @interface files and add your buttons to this collection, and then you can run a method over each object in the collection.

You can see more details [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/28/interface-builder-outlet-collections.html)